# OOP/Repository pattern: creating too many objects for different subsets of database access?

Tags: c#, oop, repository-pattern

I'm porting old VB6 code (yes yes, VB6...) to C#. I'm refactoring code to be more object-oriented, and among other things, I'm implementing repository classes to access the database.

Now, these repository classes return objects, not datasets. But I find that sometimes I only return a subset of the information an object might hold. Example: I can get a complete list of documents, with name, filepath, folder, creator, etc - or I can get document search results which only contain name and folder.

What is the best practice for these subset cases? Should I create custom objects for these database calls, that only contain the subset of data? Should I return the complete objects with only some of their fields populated? Or should I just return datasets?

Comment: Just a thought.. Your repositories should never return a `DataSet`. They should return something like a Poco. And the poco should match the TableStructure. Something like an ORM-Mapper or EntityFramework might help

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, everything should be centralized as much as possible. This could be done by creating a query object for each subset. I think you can go either way with returning objects with some fields populated or null, dependent if your database allows nulls for those specific fields.

So centralize your rules and logic with your repository classes so that each object is returned consistently based on those rules and logic.

Create an underling schema for your objects so they do not get too complex. I think what is need is an entity per object to be consider for repository. Again, creating custom objects or DTO's could create unneeded code and complexity. For the sake of integrity, keep your objects with some fields populated and others that are not needed within that subset null, that way if this information is queried later, information can be reported back that value does not exist for a specific entity.

Here is a brief example, try using POCO classes with the entity framework.

```
    public interface IRepository<TEntity, in TKey> where TEntity : class
{
   TEntity Get(TKey id);
}

public class SomeRepo1 : IRepository
{
  private readonly FileDbContext someDbContext;

   public FileRepository(FileDbContext dbContext)
   {
      someDbContext = dbContext;
   }

   public File Get(string id)
   {
     return someDbContext.Files.ToList();
   }
}
```

Example of POCO Class that can be used for files:

```
public class File
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string FileName { get; set; }

}
 public class Folder
   {
     public List<File> Files { get; set; }

   }
```

More details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

> But I find that sometimes I only return a subset of the information an object might hold.

You have just confused the object model with the persistence model.

You see, the object model doesn't care how the storage is implemented. Specifically, if there is a database behind the object model and you have tables that contain some data, you are free to map the database to your object model in any way you want. With a clever object-relational mapper you can for example split a table into two classes or have multiple classes persisted in the same table.

So, something that looks like "a subset" from the perspective of your storage, could possibly not be "a subset" from the object-model perspective.

An example specific Entity Framework 6 solution involves so called **Table Splitting** which allows you to split a model class into two classes, a class with core properties that are always loaded and another class with auxiliary properties that are lazily loaded only when you refer to the virtual property of the core class.

An example tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/table-splitting-in-entity-framework-6-code-first-approach/

(just to mention, the opposite, where two physical tables are mapped to oe model class is called **Entity splitting**)